Reference request for an Einstein quote
Einstein wrote "Pure mathematics is, in its way, the poetry of logical ideas."
According to a perimeterinstitute.ca article, it was in "a tribute to Noether published in the New York Times shortly after her death".
What is the exact reference?

The article you refer to is the following one: THE LATE EMMY NOETHER.; Professor Einstein Writes in Appreciation of a Fellow-Mathematician. However, I was unable to access the New York Times archive as it was pay-walled. But I did find a Reddit post which contains a screenshot of it. The article is indeed the source of the quote (see sentence 4, paragraph 2 in the article).

Thanks! So, for the record, the reference should be A. Einstein, The New York Times, May 4th 1935.
